# Transfer data from elasticsearch to kafka

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka

I want to transfer data of certain conditions from `elasticsearch` to `kafka`.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You could use [kafka-connect](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect) source connector for this, such as [this one](https://github.com/DarioBalinzo/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-source)

Comment: What issues are you having querying elasticsearch and writing a producer object?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35891798/4604579

Comment: @cricket_007 no, I just wonder if there exists a big data plugins, which only needs  some configurations

Comment: Okay, well, asking for off-site resources is considered off-topic for StackOverflow, just fyi, but in addition to the below answer, you could also try a general REST connector. https://github.com/llofberg/kafka-connect-rest Or you could hook up something like Apache NiFi

Comment: Maybe achieve custom source and sink using `kafka-conect` is a common solution,  but It need more work for coding and testing, and confluent does not has official support for ’kafka-connect-elasticsearch-source‘ yet,  I will try your code but may not use it in production environment.  Anyway thanks for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `logstash` for transferring data from `elasticsearch` to `kafka` finally.

`logstash` is alse a common framework for ingesting transforming and stashing data, which offers a variety of input and output plugins including `elasticsearch input` and `kafka output`.

Besides, `elasticsearch input` plugins also provide a schedule mechanism， which is very convenient for ingesting incremental data.

Comment: Hey, Can you share us the code are the link?

Comment: sorry for late answer. here is an example code hopes help you.

https://medium.com/geekculture/data-pipeline-from-kafka-to-elastic-search-using-logstash-5edca8d44d82